# CouchDB: how to use _revs_diff to get document revision ID

Tags: couchdb

I tried to test couchDB's _revs_diff api to get document revisions. Here is the command I used

```
curl -X POST http://******:******@localhost:5984/grocery-sync/_revs_diff -H "Content-type:application/json"
```

the result is

```
{"error":"unknown_error","reason":"badarg"}
```

Does anyone know the reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [CouchDB wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HttpPostRevsDiff), `_revs_diff` will return a value if the revisions for a given document are invalid.  No examples using `curl` are given.

Looking at [this mailing list posting](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.couchdb.user/14773) the problem appears to be that you need to include document and revision information, like this:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" \
   http://*:*@localhost:5984/grocery-sync/_revs_diff \
   -d '{"0d63eac0ca9a37daa062b23853a4cf4d":["1-e9e4e9c76323a267ff4f780f9f979b9f", "12-3286453e55eb2c401bc194670075f942"]}'
```

Where the dictionary key (`0d63...cf4d`) is the document id and the array are revision ids.  In this example both revisions (`1-...` and `12-...`) are present in the database so the response is

```
{}
```

If I provide a missing revision id (one I invented):

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json"  \
  http://*:*@localhost:5984/grocery-sync/_revs_diff \
  -d '{"0d63eac0ca9a37daa062b23853a4cf4d":["1-abcdef"]}'
```

The response is

```
{"0d63eac0ca9a37daa062b23853a4cf4d":{"missing":["1-abcdef"]}}
```